# Python Problematic TicTacToe Board

Tags: python

So I started a project for TicTacToe, and also I am a beginner so I don't know how to do a lot of stuff. This the result of the half hour of coding.

**I seem to have problems with debugging why Player2 isn't taking turn.**

So it asks to add more details, then I will write a few more lines, and it still asking me to add more lines.

Finally...

```
#Simple TicTacToe(Not so much)
#November 26, 2018
#1 is X, 2 is O

data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

play = True

replay = False

chs = ""

ppl = 0
def ques():
    global chs
    global replay
    a = int(input(f"{chs}:Postion(Classic Computer Number Pad Order, in number form,1-9):  "))
    if chs == "Player 1":
        if data[a-1] != "X" and data[a-1] != "O":
            data[a-1] = "X"
            replay = False
        else:
            print("PLACE TAKEN! CHOOSE ANOTHER ONE")
            replay = True
    elif chs == "Player 2":
        if data[a-1] != "O" and data[a-1] != "X":
            data[a-1] = "O"
            replay = False
        else:
            print("PLACE TAKEN! CHOOSE ANOTHER ONE")
            replay = True


    if chs == "Player 1" and replay == True:
        chs = "Player 2"
    elif chs == "Player 2" and replay == True:
        chs = "Player 1"
def board():
    print(str(data[6])+"|"+str(data[7])+"|"+str(data[8]))
    print(str(data[3])+"|"+str(data[4])+"|"+str(data[5]))
    print(str(data[0])+"|"+str(data[1])+"|"+str(data[2]))


def checkX():
    if data[0] == "X" and data[1] == "X" and data[2] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True
    elif data[3] == "X" and data[4] == "X" and data[5] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True
    elif data[6] == "X" and data[7] == "X" and data[8] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True
    elif data[0] == "X" and data[3] == "X" and data[6] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True
    elif data[1] == "X" and data[4] == "X" and data[7] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True
    elif data[2] == "X" and data[5] == "X" and data[8] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True
    elif data[0] == "X" and data[4] == "X" and data[8] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True
    elif data[2] == "X" and data[4] == "X" and data[6] == "X":
        print("Player 1 WON")
        return True




def checkO():
    if data[0] == "O" and data[1] == "O" and data[2] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True
    elif data[3] == "O" and data[4] == "O" and data[5] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True
    elif data[6] == "O" and data[7] == "O" and data[8] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True
    elif data[0] == "O" and data[3] == "O" and data[6] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True
    elif data[1] == "O" and data[4] == "O" and data[7] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True
    elif data[2] == "O" and data[5] == "O" and data[8] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True
    elif data[0] == "O" and data[4] == "O" and data[8] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True
    elif data[2] == "O" and data[4] == "O" and data[6] == "O":
        print("Player 2 WON")
        return True







def main():
    global chs
    player = input("Which shape go first?('x'for player1 or 'o'for player2):  ")
    if player == "x" or player == "X":
        print("Player 1 will go first.")
        chs = "Player 1"
    elif player == "o" or player == "O":
        print("Player 2 will go first.")
        chs = "Player 2"
    while play:
        ques()
        board()
        if checkX():
            break
        if checkO():
            break
        print("\n"*10)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never tell your program to change the player. You may fix it by alternating the value of `chs` after every turn, for example:

`if chs == "Player 1":
        if data[a-1] != "X" and data[a-1] != "O":
            data[a-1] = "X"
            replay = False
            chs = "Player 2"
        else:
            print("PLACE TAKEN! CHOOSE ANOTHER ONE")
            replay = True
    elif chs == "Player 2":
        if data[a-1] != "O" and data[a-1] != "X":
            data[a-1] = "O"
            replay = False
            chs = "Player 1"
        else:
            print("PLACE TAKEN! CHOOSE ANOTHER ONE")
            replay = True`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to change the player in section 2 there.

But in section 1 of this code, you're setting replay to false. Then it never gets to change to the next player in section 2.

Perhaps you meant to check for the 'play' variable in section 2?

```
# section 1
if chs == "Player 1":
    if data[a-1] != "X" and data[a-1] != "O":
        data[a-1] = "X"
        replay = False # after making their turn replay is false.
    else:
        print("PLACE TAKEN! CHOOSE ANOTHER ONE")
        replay = True
elif chs == "Player 2":
    if data[a-1] != "O" and data[a-1] != "X":
        data[a-1] = "O"
        replay = False
    else:
        print("PLACE TAKEN! CHOOSE ANOTHER ONE")
        replay = True

# section 2
if chs == "Player 1" and replay == True: # replay is checked here, but is false
    chs = "Player 2" # never gets run
elif chs == "Player 2" and replay == True: # replay is checked again here, but is false once more
    chs = "Player 1" # never gets run
```